# Copy one channel data to another channel in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, opencv3.0

how can I copy red channel value of a mat image to blue channel using opencv.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the whole channel? one way could be to cv::split the image and then cv::merge accordingly. See http://opencvexamples.blogspot.de/2013/10/split-and-merge-functions.html ... maybe there is a faster way to do it, but I don't know.

Comment: @Micka:i already have values in red channel and i want to copy that values to other 2 channels

Comment: In this case scanning the matrix and set values should be much faster. The red channel values are in a separate matrix? Or you want to set blue/green channels to the red one in the same matrix? Please also add some code to clarify

Comment: @NibinJose if you want to try the split and merge version, you can just add the red channel three times to the vector before merging (and dont add the other channels).

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it, split the channels and copied that to other channels

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
cv::Mat Image =cv::imread("image.jpg");
uint8_t * orig_ptr = (uint8_t*)Image.data;
for (int y = 0; y < Image.rows; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Image.cols; x++)
    {
        int R = orig_ptr[x * 3 + y*Image.step + 2];
        orig_ptr[x * 3 + y*Image.step + 1] = R;
        orig_ptr[x * 3 + y*Image.step] = R;
    }
}
```